# Декомпилятор C#

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, у меня есть одна очень интересная програмка на C#, но вот беда, она без исходника, так вот, какие есть де компиляторы C#? В инете сейчас искать не могу, т.к. он лимитный :(

Comment: Забавный получится код, могу сказать вам сразу. C# это ООП. Если вы ждете что оно вам выдаст готовые классы с методами и свойствами, то боюсь не дождетесь.

Comment: А что тогда делать?

Comment: Попробуйте декомпилировать и нам поведаете :).

Comment: Я уже сделал это, и все нормально. Код дает - а это главное.

Comment: И че? Искодники классов все по полочкам? Если да то круто.

Comment: Ага. Я уже пол программы для себя выдрал их классов.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Попробуйте свободный [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx).

Список возможностей с их страницы:

- Assembly browsing
- IL Disassembly
- Decompilation to C#
- Supports lambdas and 'yield return'
- Shows XML documentation
- Saving of resources
- Search for types/methods/properties (substring)
- Hyperlink-based type/method/property navigation
- Base/Derived types navigation
- Navigation history
- BAML to XAML decompiler
- Save Assembly as C# Project
- Find usage of field/method
- Extensible via plugins (MEF)

Comment: Спасибо это именно то что я искал!

Comment: Отличный инструмент! Спасибо!

Comment: Ну вот, а я только собрался игру на C# делать. Как её продавать, если защиту вмиг снесут с таким декомпилятором?

Comment: Для этого существуют так называемые обфускаторы. Ихняя задача - "запутывание" кода: переименовывание методов, классов, полей, иногда переписывание методов, etc. Однако и они не дают полной гарантии, т.к. всегда найдутся любопытные.

Comment: Про обфускаторы я знаю, но

>Однако и они не дают полной гарантии

 Такая вот проблема. Бесплатная версия Dotfuscator'а может только переименовывать, за другие функции придётся платить. Есть ли нормальный бесплатный обфускатор, который использует все способы запутывания кода, а не только переменных?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй JetBrains dotPeek. А еще есть платный Reflector с кучей сладких плюшек им можно пользоваться в триале  дней