# Как можно вскрыть приложение, узнать на чем оно?

Tags: reverse-engineering

Есть только exe файл, нужно узнать исходный код.

Comment: Вам нужен какой-нибудь дизассемблер. Один из самых популярных -- Ida Pro. Превращаете ваш екзешник в ассемблерный код, а там уже только анализировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно узнать, на каком языке написано приложение, то отлично выручает инструмент **DIE**. Он выдаёт полную информацию о библиотеках DLL и исполняемых файлах EXE. А дальше дизассемблер или отладчик, чтобы выполнить приложение по-шагам. При этом исходный код получите исключительно на ассемблере.

[image: Анализатор DIE]

Comment: приложение кажется использует .net . Есть ли способ получить исходники от такого приложения не на ассемблере?

Comment: возможно и есть, но лично мне не встречался такой софт.

Comment: @pecenka ,нет. Приложение собирается в машинный код ровно так как это посчитает нужным компилятор. Повысить читабельность машинного кода можно лишь переведя его в ассемблер. Может уже и есть ухищрения, но я не видел такого ни разу

Comment: @SeeNax а как же dot peek? или ILSpy? или Reflector ? Всё спокойно декомпилируется.  ...... кстати вот ещё целый список https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/57213/191482    но самый топ dot peek.

Comment: @pecenka ↑↑↑↑↑↑